# grep files based on time stamp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

This should be pretty simple, but I am not figuring it out. I have a large code base more than 4GB under Linux. A few header files and xml files are generated during build (using gnu make). If it matters the header files are generated based on xml files.

I want to search for a keyword in header file that was last modified after a time instance ( Its my start compile time), and similarly xml files, but separate grep queries.

If I run it on all possible header or xml files, it take a lot of time. Only those that were auto generated. Further the search has to be recursive, since there are a lot of directories and sub-directories.

Comment: You might want to include examples of your current commands. Saves us the trouble of pointing out the obvious stuff that you already know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To find `'pattern'` in all files newer than `some_file` in the current directory and its sub-directories recursively:

```
find -newer some_file -type f -exec grep 'pattern' {} +
```

You could specify the timestamp directly in `date -d` format and use other `find` tests e.g., `-name`, `-mmin`.

The file list could also be generate by your build system if `find` is too slow.

More specific tools such as [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/), `etags`, [`GCCSense`](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/) might be used instead of `grep`.

Comment: Thanks, I came across something more valuable than just answer. I had never come across GCCSense. I was looking for eclipse code completion capabilities in vim. Guess its very recently developed.

Comment: Ah ha! It's so obvious!

Answer (score 20):

You could use the `find` command:

```
find . -mtime 0 -type f
```

prints a list of all files (`-type f`) in and below the current directory (`.`) that were modified in the last 24 hours (`-mtime 0`, 1 would be 48h, 2 would be 72h, ...). Try

```
grep "pattern" $(find . -mtime 0 -type f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this. Because if `find` doesn't return a file, then `grep` will keep waiting for an input halting the script.

```
find . -mtime 0 -type f | xargs grep "pattern"
```