# In Unix how to search string only in few files in directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, aix

I need to grep for string named "Account_Id" in my logs folder. However, there are 10000  log files there and i need to search this only in files which were created in last 30 days.

I need output like this in a csv file. This is just an example

```
File_name       Matched_string           Line
program1.log    where account_id1         14
program2.log    substr(account_id,1,4)    45
```

I did try using `grep -nHi "Account_Id" *` 
However it searches entire directory and takes a lot of time

Any help is really really appreciated

Comment: Take a look at the `find ` command

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep files based on time stamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851667/grep-files-based-on-time-stamp)

Answer (score 2):

```
DIRECTORY=logs
echo -e "File_name\tMatched_string\tLine"
for i in $(find $DIRECTORY -ctime -30)
do 
    grep -nHIs "Account_Id" $i | awk -F ":" '{print $1"\011" $3 "\011" $2}'
done
```

I'm not sure you'll get the output like you specified in your question because of tab align issues

**UPDATE**

Oneliner which starts in current dir. It uses `find -exec` and `awk printf`. Probably you need to adjust printf format (`"%-40s\t%-40s\t%-4s\n"`) :

```
find . -ctime -30 -exec grep -nHIs "Account_Id" {} \; | awk -F ":" 'BEGIN { printf "%-40s\t%-40s\t%-4s\n" , "File_name", "Matched_string", "Line" } { printf "%-40s\t%-40s\t%-4s\n", $1, $3, $2}' > out.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

grep -Hin Account_Id `find * -mtime -30` |awk -F":" '{print $1 "\t"  $3"\t" $2}' >> xyz.csv

If you have the file names in the specific pattern then you can add that pattern in find , like following

grep -Hin Account_Id `find program* -mtime -30` |awk -F":" '{print $1 "\t"  $3"\t" $2}' >> xyz.csv

Note: I don’t know why tilt symbol is disappearing from my comments
Make sure you put tilt(the keyboard button bellow to Esc) before word find and after the -30 in the above command.